# How does the "in" instruction nesting works?

Tags: ocaml

I'm struggling to understand the way that the "in" instruction works, I have an exam in a few days and even though I fell pretty confident with the way ocaml works, there's a lot of previous exams that brings me to some scoping questions, as far as I know ocaml is a static scope language, so if for example you declare a value and you use it inside a function (without passing it as an argument of course), even if you overwrite the value the function will still use the previous one, for example

```
let a = 5;;
let f x = a+x;;
let a = 1;;
f 1;;
```

Will return 6 even though the a value has been overwritten, but there are some pretty sketchy questions in the exam, like for example

```
let a = 6 in
let b x = a + x in
let a = 42 in
b a;;
```

This one confuses me a lot, how does the "in" work? I know that this returns 48, but I'm struggling to see a pattern that I can use to understand how the scoping works when you use the "in" instruction.

Any explanation will be appreciated really much

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will return 6 even though the a value has been overwritten

It's not overwritten. You create a new variable with the same name. I.e., you don't change the existing variable - you create a new one which hides the existing one. What happens is this:

```
let a1 = 5;;
let f x = a1 + x;;
let a2 = 1;;
f 1;;
```

The same in the second example:

```
let a1 = 6 in
let b x = a1 + x in
let a2 = 42 in
b a2;;
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is way more clear now, anyway I still struggle to understand the "in" instruction, like for example, how is a variable accessible to/from another? Should it be before or after the in? Have you got any good resource explaining how does it work? Anyway, really thanks for the valuable answer :D

Comment: You are welcome. I'm not sure I understand the question: you write `let x = .. in expr`, and now `x` can be used in `expr`. I'm not sure if it helps, but you may check this: https://www2.lib.uchicago.edu/keith/ocaml-class/definitions.html

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I probably didn't ask it so well, but  you managed to understand the question and you gave the answer I was looking for, I will definitely check the resource you gave, thanks again :D